# Generate a random variable which is uncorrelated with errors in r

Tags: r, random, economics

I generated an error in r

```
u1<-rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1);
```

And I want to generate a random normal variable x ~ i.i.d.N(n, 0, 4) but this is not correlated with u1 i.e. `corr(x, u1)` is zero.

How can I, define this in R?

Answer (score 2):

Generation of two uncorrelated variables:

```
n <- 1e3
u1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
x <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 4)
```

Please note that **estimated** correlation coefficient will not be exactly 0, but it will be close to 0.

```
> cor(x, u1)
[1] -0.01885482
```

Answer (score 1):

Any two random Gaussian variables will have a theoretical correlation of 0, as long as n is large enough.

```
set.seed(1)
n=1000000
u1<-rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1)
x<-rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=4)

cor(x, u1)
```

Output:

```
0.0007637239
```